# Trouble with function keys

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, macos-ventura

Im a developer and I use macOS Ventura. I have 2 keyboards, one of the notebook and another apple keyboard with keypad.

While using IDEs like VsCode, I would like that the functions keys would work like old-fashioned function keys, and when not using IDEs they would behave regularly.

Another option would be the functions keys of the external keyboard working old-fashion and the keyboard of the MacBook working in the new model...

is any of that possible?

Comment: No, neither are possible. The behavior is set OS wide and irrespective of the keyboards connected.